# How to create wordpress page that is child to a post?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a page that links to a post, but the url of the page should begin with, where the post url ends.

Example - ***abc.com/antivirus-for-pc*** this is a post and i want to create a page ***abc.com/antivirus-for-pc/download/***

How can i do this?

I tried creating a new page with this url ***abc.com/antivirus-for-pc/download/*** but the slash (/) is converted into (-) every time i publish the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the parent page here:

[image]

Comment: HI Bob, the above solution is used for pages. But i want this for example - domain>blog post>page or domain>parent blog post> child page

please help i am serching for this over 2 days on internet..